# How to get all the <a> tags from the <body> tag using PHP DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

I am using PHP's `curl` for getting webpage data, and for extracting `<a>` tags from the `<body>` I am using DOM Document, but it is creating an error.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=B5GBVezbDeHA8geU8pfYBw",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Webbot UA'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (isset($result)){
  $doc = new DomDocument;
  $doc->Load($result);
  var_dump($doc['a']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use DomDocument, use `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` but that's just because I believe it's faster in execution, may be wrong though.

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//a');
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'a: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

To use DomDocument look at `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`

```
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Why not use "DomDocument"?

Comment: what is SimpleXMLElement::xpath I am not introduced with this function?

Comment: and according to James Why not use DOM?

Comment: @James You're right Xpath was the first thing that came to my mind, have updated with a DomDocument solution

Comment: @Catharsis It worked, thanks you were right XML is the better way than HTML Manipulation.